# Can I share my private GitHub repository by link?

Tags: git, github

I have a Java application in a private repository on GitHub and I would like to share it with someone who doesn't have an account. I didn't find any option on the site for this.

Is there a way to do this? Collaborators can be only GitHub users.

Comment: You need to add the others as collaborators to the project.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

There is no way to share private repository among non-Github users.

You need the Github account and be [added as collaborator to the project](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/).

Comment: It is now possible using a read-only token, see @nguyendown response https://stackoverflow.com/a/76922082/3118929

Comment: Github recently added this feature.

please read the answer from @nguyendown
starting with "You can use read-only access token to share a private repository."

Answer (score 64):

You can use [gitfront.io](https://gitfront.io) for this purpose.
You can give users to read-only access to keep your secure

Comment: hmmm.. "warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository"

Answer (score 61):

Use https://gitfront.io/. The steps to follow are:

1. Visit the https://gitfront.io/ page and click on `Get Started`.
2. Click on **Add Repository**.
3. Copy the link to the private repository you want to share using **SSH**. It should look something like `git@github.com:your_username/repo_name.git`

[image: SSH Link on github]

4. Paste it where it says `Repository URL`. Press `Add`.

[image: Repository Form in gitfront]

5. Copy the key shown in the text box and click on `Open repository Deploy keys on GitHub.`

[image: Key generation on gitfront]

6. Add the **deploy key** to github.

[image: Add a deploy key on github]

7. Hit **Build** and it will generate a url that you can view and share by clicking the **View** button.

Comment: I have followed the steps but I have a size of repository greater than 100MB. So is there anotehr way to share for free?

Comment: useful, anyway this does not prevent making a copy of the source code

Answer (score 27):

You can use read-only access token to share a private repository.

```
git clone https://<username>:<token>@github.com/<username>/<repo>.git
```

To generate a new token:

1. Go to Settings > Developer Settings > Personal access tokens > Fine-grained tokens > Generate new token.
2. Select the repositories you want to share under Repository access > Only select repositories.
3. Set the access level of the token to read-only in Permissions > Repository permissions > Contents > Access: read-only.
4. Finally, click on Generate token.

Comment: Earlier answers might have been correct when written, but currently I think this should be voted as "accepted answer"

Comment: This is definitely the best answer. No 3rd party tools needed and works like a charm. Just in case I'll add that <username> should be replaced in both cases with the repo owner's username.

Comment: how do you get the link then to the repository to access reading from website ?

Comment: The best answer! definitely should be replaced with the accepted answer!