# Sharing private git repo via access link

Tags: git, repository, share

I have worked on a private project and would like to put it on my resume.

For that I am looking for a **git service** which allows me to **share an access link to my repo**, where anybody who has received that access link can read the contents of my repo without requiring the invited to have an account on the particular git web service and without me knowing any details about the consumer of the access link in advance.

It should basically work like a GoogleDrive or OneDrive share-via-link.

Ideally i should be able to set the expiration date of the access link and be able to generate different access links.

**Now does such a Git web service exist?** Currently I am using BitBucket, but it does not have this feature. I dont like the idea of putting my project on unrestricted public display.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is:

- [not possible with GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264165/can-i-share-my-private-github-repository-by-link) (you would need to add a user as a collaborator of a private repo)
- discussed, but not yet implemented on GitLab: [issue 20549: "Share private project via URL"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20549) (since April 2016)

So you might need to use a third-party option (like the ones you mention, or [GitFront](https://gitfront.io/) -- [from Serbia](https://gitfront.io/terms.html#:%7E:text=Any%20claim%20related%20to%20GitFront%27s%20Website%20shall%20be%20governed%20by%20the%20laws%20of%20Republic%20of%20Serbia) -- mentioned below,) to package/publish (and update) your repository, for any user to access it with a link. For example, publish it as a [bundle (one file)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309).

Answer (score 14):

You can use [GitFront](https://gitfront.io) to share private git repositories.

It is a web application that allows you to import a repository and create a read-only version of it, which is sharable via link. The person receiving the link doesn't need to have an account to view the repository.

Disclosure: Affiliated with GitFront.

Comment: Based on the URL of your link being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you must disclose that it's your site in your post. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [What signifies "Good" self promotion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212), [some tips and advice about self-promotion](/help/promotion), [What is the exact definition of "spam" for Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260638), and [What makes something spam](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035).

Comment: @GitFront what's the cost to use GitFront?

Comment: GitFront is free to use at no cost while in beta.

Comment: You should add Oauth to make it easier to give permission to private repositories

Comment: This is perfect (I need to share a private repo for a class, but can't make it public). Some feedback, it's not the most obvious to figure out the deploy keys for GitHub. I figured it out eventually, but a better how-to page / instructions would be nice

Comment: @Pedro it does Oauth through email. I like how they made it optional since otherwise it gets deleted in a week

Comment: @GitFront, is it possible the "Clone" button to be disabled in a repository?

Comment: @muca Currently, there is no option to disable it.

Comment: This is great, except that GitFront doesn't have support for PDFs. Would have been great to use GitFront to host my resume.

Answer (score 1):

As for GitFront, I faced insecure behavior. I recommend avoiding it, or at least using it carefully.

Details:

- Shared repository and its URL is still accessible even if I removed the Repo from the list of my account.
- The shared URL is still accessible even if I deleted my account.

Eventually, after 1x minute, that URL becomes 404.
The service should have invalidated the shared URL rather than processing it asynchronously. It could cause undeletable resources if the asynchronous process has failed.

Comment: In addition these days site is broken, in login you get error "unable to send token" and there is no way to contact them .. You lose access to your linka, crazy!

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to our attention. The issue was fixed a while ago. When you remove a repository it will be synchronously deleted and the link will return 404 right away.
We might miss the issues reported on StackOverflow, so it's better to contact support if you find them. We are quite responsive.

Answer (score 0):

**What about [repo-view](https://github.com/ibrahemesam/repo-view)?** - a project I created after having a similar issue sharing private projects as part of my CV.

It is a static web page that uses Github REST API to preview repos.
It lets employers see your private GitHub repositories in your CV (with your permission of course) without making them public ↗️↗️.

Unlike [GitFront](https://gitfront.io), it has no 100MB repo size limit.

If you'd like to see how it works, there's a [demo of it here](https://ibrahemesam.github.io/repo-view/?token=Z2l0aHViX3BhdF8xMUFLUEZNNEkwbzc4WkZYT3B0VWd0X1lwYjB5MU84WXNsY3RCNmpRQTg3b1ZwVjExZDFEN25OWlNheFl4NFFIbm9FMjNJUDRRNWNSQUUwZVNw&owner=ibrahemesam&repo=repo-view-demo).